# How to change the connectionstring of a entity framework (model first application) with azure database connection string?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I am actually deploying my web application in to azure and am trying to use azure database instead of on premises database And am using entity framework (model first approach). can someone please let me know how to replace the connectionstring ? and where to replace it (either in azure app service or VS webconfig )?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What Entity-Framework and asp.net version are you using? What have you tried so far?

Comment: .Net 4.5.1 & EF Version=6.0, I have tried replacing the web.config con string with Azure SQL con string , but its throwing the exception."System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException: The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development. This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity Framework connection string is included in the app.config .

Comment: YAAYYY . i got  solution . its working now.